# 'conda create -n abc python=3.7' process getting stuck on my Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, ide, environment, anaconda3

I'm new to python and trying to create an virtual environment after I installed Anaconda 3.

When I conducted the following code on the console inside Anaconda 3,
it takes forever with the Anaconda seemingly getting freezed and I cannot make the environment.

`conda create -n aipractice37 python=3.7`

Below are the information of my current conda environment.

```
conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

```
 conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
       user config file : C:\Users\Y\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Y\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Y\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Y\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Y\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Y\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Would anybody tell me how to create a virtual environment properly? Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on macOS, Conda 4.8.2.

Comment: @AMC thanks for your comment. I'm using Windows 10 to get this error.
Please tell me if there's any information you need to find a solution to it.